# About the total mint token in polkadot and kusama

Tags: polkadot, kusama, token

How many tokens are minted in Polkadot and Kusama in the past year? Is there any way to find out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could query the total issuance at different block heights/hash.

Then compare the results.

But this will ignore the burned tokens if you don't mind.

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to find out how many new mint tokens were given to treasury.